# String to Lucene Query

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.Net and lucene query can change string. In my application,
search are saved and re-searched using Boolean Query. I saved lucene query syntax like 
+Field1:value +(+Field2:value) and I want to change string to lucene query. I find it in google but the suitable solution for my application is not found. Writing custom class is useful for simple query but I'm worry for complex query containing AND or OR and many +,-
syntax in query.
So please tell me how to do.
Thank for any advice !!

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the Lucene QueryParser.

Comment: Yes,it worked with Lucene QueryParser. Thank for your answer.